# How to size a ScrollView to fit 60% of the screen from bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a ScrollView that occupies about 60% of the screen from the bottom. The screen is in landscape mode and the scrollview is the only view element in this activity. I can get it to work on a 800x480 emulator screen by forcing layout margins (see XML code below) but when I switch to a higher res screen the scrollview will occupy more than 60% of the screen and as a result it covers up some of the information on the background image. Can someone please advice on how to keep the view at around 60% of screen size, and preferably be able to handle different screen sizes?

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/safety_base"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollSafety"
        android:layout_width="435dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSafety"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSafety"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgSafety_desc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/safety_info" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use `Linear Layout` outside `Scroll View` and then assign `0.6` weight to your `Scroll View`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollSafety"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSafety"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSafety"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="Blah blah"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It did not quite work. The 2-to-3 ratio coverage works fine until I added the ImageView. In other words, without the imageview, when I look at the graphic layout preview in eclipse, the borders show the ratio correctly. However, when I include the ImageView, all of sudden the Imageview takes up almost the entire screen and fails to keep the 2-3 ratio. Any idea why??

Comment: You're not scaling the image.  Inside your ImageView, try adding android:scaleType="centerInside" or android:scaleType="fitCenter".

Comment: It turns out that if I run it in the emulator everything is fine. Perhaps a bug with the layout preview not correctly showing the correct ratio??

Comment: Don't know.  It renders correctly in my layout preview.  Did you select a theme that will provide a suitable contrasting background color?